# SQL Find latest date where condition doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm quite new to SQL and working on a query that has been thoroughly defeating me for a while now.  I come to this site often - it's a terrific resource thanks to all of your expertise, and generally I find what I need, but this time I think my query is a bit too specific and I've not found something applicable.  Could someone give me a hand, please?

I have two tables: one Client table and one Contact (aka appointment) table.  What I need to find are all of the clients' most recent appointment days (before a certain date, in this case '11/08/2015') where the Outcome for any appointment on that day is NOT a '2'.  Each client may have more than one appointment on a single day, and an Outcome of '2' for any of those appointments means that we have to ignore the whole day and move back to the next most recent day..

For example, Client '3' should have a returned appointment date of '01/07/2015' (and just one row) and not the two rows for '16/07/2015', because one of the appointments on '16/07/2015' had an Outcome of '2'.  All other values for Outcome are acceptable (including NULL), just not '2'.

The multiple appointment on the same day bit is the part that I'm finding tricky - I can find the latest appointment day using a Select MAX (or TOP 1) statement, but when I add on a "<> '2'" it still continues to return the same days that may have an Outcome '2' because other appointments on that same day have another Outcome.  I've been trying to play around with my tables and GROUP BY and NOT EXIST, but I don't seem to be making any headway.

```
Contact
ClientID    AppDate Outcome
1   30/07/2015 17:00    2
1   01/07/2015 17:00    3
2   03/03/2015 16:00    NULL
2   01/03/2015 16:00    NULL
3   16/07/2015 15:40    6
3   16/07/2015 15:40    2
3   01/07/2015 15:40    3
4   05/08/2015 12:30    6
4   05/08/2015 12:30    2
4   01/08/2015 12:30    3
5   23/07/2015 15:30    2
5   23/07/2015 15:30    NULL
5   01/07/2015 15:30    4
6   20/07/2015 10:10    NULL
6   20/07/2015 10:10    2
6   01/07/2015 10:10    6
7   23/07/2015 15:40    2
7   01/07/2015 15:40    1
7   23/06/2015 15:40    8
8   13/07/2015 11:30    2
8   13/07/2015 11:30    6
8   01/07/2015 11:30    2
8   01/06/2015 11:30    3
9   29/07/2015 17:00    3
9   29/07/2015 17:00    6
10  14/07/2015 11:00    NULL
10  01/07/2015 11:00    5


Client      
ClientID    Forename    Surname
1       I       B
2       J       B
3       S       C
4       S       T
5       P       C
6       K       D
7       P       E
8       P       H
9       S       F
10      A       G
```

Apologies if I'm missing something glaringly obvious!  Thanks for reading and for any responses.  I attach my truncated query for your general amusement...

```
SELECT
cli.ClientID ,
cli.Forename ,
cli.Surname ,
con.AppDate ,
con.Outcome 


FROM
Client AS cli

INNER JOIN
Contact AS con
ON cli.ClientID = con.ClientID 
AND con.AppDate =
    (SELECT MAX(con1.AppDate) 
    FROM Contact AS con1
    WHERE con.ClientID = con1.ClientID 
    AND con1.AppDate < '11/08/2015  00:00:00'
    AND con1.Outcome <> '2')


ORDER BY
cli.ClientID
```

EDIT:

Thank you to Mr Linoff for the Cross Apply query, it worked perfectly.

Sorry that I didn't include the expected output earlier.  For reference (for anyone else working with a similar problem in future) I was looking to obtain:

```
Appointments        
Client ID   Act Date and Time   Outcome
1   01/07/2015 17:00    3
2   03/03/2015 16:00    NULL
3   01/07/2015 15:40    3
4   01/08/2015 12:30    3
5   01/07/2015 15:30    4
6   01/07/2015 10:10    6
7   01/07/2015 15:40    1
8   01/06/2015 11:30    3
9   29/07/2015 17:00    3
9   29/07/2015 17:00    6
10  14/07/2015 11:00    NULL
```

Comment: Not clear on the question, can you please provide the expected output from the tables?

Comment: what is missing from this question is the "expected result"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `cross apply` is the best approach to this:

```
select c.*, con.*
from client c cross apply
     (select top 1 con.*
      from (select con.*,
                   sum(case when Outcome = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ClientId, AppDate) as num2s
            from contact con
            where con.ClientId = c.ClientId and
                  con.AppDate < '2015-11-08'
           ) con
      where num2s = 0
      order by AppDate desc
     ) con;
```

In this case, `cross apply` works a lot like a correlated subquery, but you can return multiple values.  The subquery uses window functions to count the number of "2" on a given day and the rest of the logic should be pretty obvious.

This returns one row from the most recent date with appropriate appointments.  If you want multiple such rows, use `with ties`.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to have a condition which picks out all the Dates where Outcome is two and filter them out.

Something like this:

```
WITH ClientCTE AS
(
SELECT MAX(con1.AppDate) AS AppDate ,ClientID
    FROM Contact AS con1
    WHERE con.ClientID = con1.ClientID 
    AND con1.AppDate < '11/08/2015  00:00:00'
    AND con1.Outcome  <> '2'
    AND con1.AppDate NOT IN (SELECT AppDate FROM Contact WHERE Outcome  = '2')) 

SELECT 
* FROM Client C
INNER JOIN
Contact AS con
ON cli.ClientID = con.ClientID 
INNER JOIN ClientCTE  CTE
ON cli.ClientID = CTE.ClientCTE
AND CTE.AppDate = con.AppDate
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query.
It uses the `MAX(case...) OVER( partition BY CAST(AppDate as DATE)` windowed function to flag all appointments which have a 2 outcome on same day along with `WHERE` clause to filter out dates.
This `flag` is then used in outer `WHERE` clause to remove unwanted data and joined on contacts and client tables

```
SELECT
    cli.ClientID ,
    cli.Forename ,
    cli.Surname ,
    con.AppDate ,
    con.Outcome 
  from 
    client cli right join contact con
        on con.ClientID=cli.ClientID
    inner join
    (
        select ClientID,MAX(AppDate)as lastDate from 
                (       select *,  
                            MAX(CASE when ISNULL(Outcome,1) =2 then 1 else 0 end) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(AppDate as DATE),ClientID ORDER BY AppDate) as flag 
                        from Contact 
                        where AppDate< '2015-11-08'
                ) p 
            where flag =0  group by ClientID
        ) s
on s.ClientId=con.ClientID and s.lastDate=con.AppDate
```

Also here's the link to sql fiddle for demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c519d/2